# How can manage multidimensional array in foreach() for tree view while multidimensional array form of multi level

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I have this tree view of my nested array:

[image: The Tree view]

My questions:

- I need to remove empty subarrays from this array, but `array_filter()` does not do this in a nested array. How can I achieve this?
- What is the right way to use a multidimensional array in my case?
- How to use a nested `foreach()` when I have a multidimensional array?

I have the following code:

```
foreach($legs as $element => $child_2){ 
    $result .= "{'name': '".$child_2['fullname']."', 'title': '".$child_2['gcn_id']."',";
    $result .= "'children': [";
    foreach($child_2 as $element_1 => $child_3){
        $result .="{'name': '".$child_3."', 'title': '".$child_3."',";
        $result .= "'children': [";
        foreach($child_3 as $element_2 => $child_4){
            $result.= "{ 'name': '".$child_4."', 'title': '".$child_4."' ,";
            $result .= "'children': [";
            /* foreach($child_4 as $k3=>$v3){
                #array_filter($v3);
                $result .= "{'name': '".$v3['fullname']."', 'title': '".$v3['gcn_id']."'},"; 

                }
            */
            $result .= "]},";
        }
        $result .= "]},";
    }
    $result .= "]";
    $result .= "},";
}
```

I have the following array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 11312
        [fullname] => Wendy-Lynn Barr
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 5064
        [fullname] => Ed Kilgour
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 10276
        [fullname] => Joseph Melendez Motijo
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 10050
        [fullname] => DIOGENES  ORTEGA
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 10050
        [fullname] => DIOGENES  ORTEGA
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [gcn_id] => 5371
        [fullname] => Roberto  Montero
        [referral_id] => 5063
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 11303
                [fullname] => Pauline Blake
                [referral_id] => 11312
            )

        [1] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 11302
                [fullname] => Craig Corbitt
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5175
                        [fullname] => Kristi  Iles
                        [referral_id] => 11302
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 6013
                                [fullname] => Joshua  Iles
                                [referral_id] => 5175
                            )

                        [1] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6308
                        [fullname] => Chris Chowning
                        [referral_id] => 11302
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 10039
                                [fullname] => Martha  Rios
                                [referral_id] => 6308
                            )

                        [1] => 
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 10020
                                [fullname] => Mel  Navarrette
                                [referral_id] => 6308
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 10040
                                        [fullname] => Aaron  Thompson
                                        [referral_id] => 10020
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 10013
                                [fullname] => April Young
                                [referral_id] => 6308
                            )

                        [5] => 
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 6239
                [fullname] => Glen Starr
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [3] => 
        [4] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 5155
                [fullname] => Allen Taylor
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5309
                        [fullname] => Deborah Taylor
                        [referral_id] => 5155
                    )

                [1] => 
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 5078
                [fullname] => Roger  Grosser
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 7643
                        [fullname] => Sam Negrete
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5922
                                [fullname] => Claudia Negrete
                                [referral_id] => 7643
                            )

                        [1] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5319
                        [fullname] => Richard Phillips
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [3] => 
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6224
                        [fullname] => Mike South
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [5] => 
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5079
                        [fullname] => Keith Gibson
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [7] => 
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6759
                        [fullname] => Lamar White
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [9] => 
                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5100
                        [fullname] => Sharlette  Poe
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [11] => 
                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6600
                        [fullname] => Ohanna  McKenzie
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7391
                                [fullname] => Maria Ramm 
                                [referral_id] => 6600
                            )

                        [1] => 
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 7492
                        [fullname] => Kyle  Grosser
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [15] => 
                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10007
                        [fullname] => Rachael  Grosser
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [17] => 
                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5122
                        [fullname] => Joe Simpson
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5189
                                [fullname] => Alan Wright
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [1] => 
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5577
                                [fullname] => Haley  Simpson
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [3] => 
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5167
                                [fullname] => Carl  Troutt
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5168
                                        [fullname] => Eugene  Martinez
                                        [referral_id] => 5167
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5168
                                        [fullname] => Eugene  Martinez
                                        [referral_id] => 5167
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7686
                                [fullname] => James  Matthew Guy
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7843
                                        [fullname] => Ethan  Guy
                                        [referral_id] => 7686
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 10070
                                [fullname] => Rogelio Perez
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [9] => 
                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7125
                                [fullname] => Floyd Bowen
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [11] => 
                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7773
                                [fullname] => Kyle Overton
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [13] => 
                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5972
                                [fullname] => Kevin Farrell
                                [referral_id] => 5122
                            )

                        [15] => 
                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5689
                        [fullname] => Troy  Shutt
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [21] => 
                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5588
                        [fullname] => Keith  Noble
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [23] => 
                [24] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5127
                        [fullname] => Stewart Allen
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [25] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5448
                                [fullname] => Javier Ballesteros
                                [referral_id] => 5127
                            )

                        [1] => 
                    )

                [26] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5180
                        [fullname] => Travis Dooley
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5246
                                [fullname] => Fackrell's  Service
                                [referral_id] => 5180
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5676
                                        [fullname] => LuAnn  Fackrell
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7784
                                        [fullname] => Chad Barnhart
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5246
                                [fullname] => Fackrell's  Service
                                [referral_id] => 5180
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5676
                                        [fullname] => LuAnn  Fackrell
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7784
                                        [fullname] => Chad Barnhart
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5246
                                [fullname] => Fackrell's  Service
                                [referral_id] => 5180
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5676
                                        [fullname] => LuAnn  Fackrell
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7784
                                        [fullname] => Chad Barnhart
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5246
                                [fullname] => Fackrell's  Service
                                [referral_id] => 5180
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 5676
                                        [fullname] => LuAnn  Fackrell
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [1] => 
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7784
                                        [fullname] => Chad Barnhart
                                        [referral_id] => 5246
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                    )

                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5166
                        [fullname] => Adan Mosqueda
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [29] => 
                [30] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5349
                        [fullname] => EDMOND WILSON
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [31] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7380
                                [fullname] => Rich Anderson
                                [referral_id] => 5349
                            )

                        [1] => 
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 7346
                                [fullname] => Peter  Smith
                                [referral_id] => 5349
                            )

                        [3] => 
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 6722
                                [fullname] => Larry Schaben
                                [referral_id] => 5349
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 7148
                                        [fullname] => Cam Callender
                                        [referral_id] => 6722
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [gcn_id] => 7313
                                                [fullname] => Sherrie Callender
                                                [referral_id] => 7148
                                            )

                                        [1] => 
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [gcn_id] => 10009
                                        [fullname] => Kathy Schaben
                                        [referral_id] => 6722
                                    )

                                [3] => 
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 10011
                                [fullname] => Cornelius Reed
                                [referral_id] => 5349
                            )

                        [7] => 
                    )

                [32] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5320
                        [fullname] => Joe Coon
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [33] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [gcn_id] => 5573
                                [fullname] => Denise Coon
                                [referral_id] => 5320
                            )

                        [1] => 
                    )

                [34] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10168
                        [fullname] => Jerry Curtis 
                        [referral_id] => 5078
                    )

                [35] => 
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 5310
                [fullname] => Rodney  Licari
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6041
                        [fullname] => Bryan  Russel Sevrence
                        [referral_id] => 5310
                    )

                [1] => 
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [gcn_id] => 5097
                [fullname] => James Yates
                [referral_id] => 5064
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10045
                        [fullname] => Christopher Edwards
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [1] => 
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 7193
                        [fullname] => Ed Kilgour
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [3] => 
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5647
                        [fullname] => Talonda Yates
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [5] => 
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 6228
                        [fullname] => Calvin  Pearson
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [7] => 
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10105
                        [fullname] => Marsha Wade
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [9] => 
                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5677
                        [fullname] => Brenda  Joyner
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [11] => 
                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 7670
                        [fullname] => Bonny  Lewis
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [13] => 
                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5231
                        [fullname] => Brent  Coursey
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [15] => 
                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5971
                        [fullname] => James  Yates, II
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [17] => 
                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 5602
                        [fullname] => Glenn  Yates
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [19] => 
                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10004
                        [fullname] => Sarah  Williams
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [21] => 
                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 10004
                        [fullname] => Sarah  Williams
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [34] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 7041
                        [fullname] => Lamont Bartlett
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [35] => 
                [36] => Array
                    (
                        [gcn_id] => 0
                        [fullname] => Eric Haut
                        [referral_id] => 5097
                    )

                [37] => 
            )

    )
)
```

[multidimensional array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOk1w.png)

The desired output for the above input would start like this:

```
{ 
    "children": [{
        "name": "Wendy-Lynn Barr", 
        "title": "11312", 
        "children": [{
            "name": "Pauline Blake", 
            "title": "11303", 
            "children":[{
                "name":"Pauline Blake",
                "title":"11312",
            }]
        }]
    },{
        "title": "5064", 
        "name": "Ed Kilgour", 
        "referral_id": "5063", 
        'children': [{ 
            'name': 'Glen Starr', 
            'title': '6239' 
        },{ 
            'name': 'Allen Taylor',
            'title': '5155'
        },{ 
            'name': 'Roger Grosser', 
            'title': '5078'
        },{
            'name': 'Rodney Licari',
            'title': '5310'
        },{
            'name': 'Craig Corbitt',
            'title':'11302'
        },{ 
            'name': 'James Yates', 
            'title': '5097'
        }]
    }, 
    { /* ...etc */ },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? Secondly, you should try `echo json_encode($legs);`.

Comment: what json_encode will do ? that is for graphical view.. nested loop will not be able to run

Comment: You seem to build a string in `$result` that is much like building a JSON string. That is exactly what `json_encode` does. You should not do this "manually", as you'll have issues as soon as strings contain a quote, ...etc.

Comment: you r right but there aren't any type of error in this section, i m unable to manage foreach loop, its give blank array in view .                                   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: gcn_id                                                                   
Message: Undefined index: fullname
Filename: controllers/UserAccount.php

Line Number: 435

Comment: That is because you apparently have a sub array which does not have the `gcn_id` key. Better test first if it is present with `if (isset($child_2["gcn_id"])) { ... }`. It seems in your case this only can happen when the subarray is empty, so then you need a recursive `array_filter`: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `array_filter` does not work recursively.

Here is a recursive function that does the job of taking out `null` values:

```
function array_filter_recursive($arr, $cb = null) {
    if (empty($cb)) {
        $cb = function ($el) {
            return $el;
        };
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) $val = array_filter_recursive($val, $cb);
        if ($cb($val)) $result[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In general you need recursion (a function that calls itself) to solve problems involving arbitrary deeply nested arrays.

Now to your actual desired output (which I transferred from your comments into your question): that looks like JSON, for which you can use `json_encode`. There should never be a reason to build such a string yourself.

So you should never write something like this:

```
$result.= "{ 'name': '".$child_4."', 'title': '".$child_4."' ,";
```

For generating the specific output you are looking for, you could use this function:

```
function convert($arr) {
    $result = [];
    $byId = [];

    function recurse(&$result, &$byId, $arr) {
        if (!is_array($arr)) return;
        if (isset($arr["gcn_id"])) {
            $parent = $arr["referral_id"];
            $record = [
                "name" => $arr["fullname"],
                "title" => $arr["gcn_id"]
            ];
            $byId[$arr["gcn_id"]] = &$record; 
            if (isset($byId[$parent])) {
                $byId[$parent]["children"][] = &$record;
            } else {
                $result[] = &$record;
            }
        } else {
            foreach($arr as $child) {
                recurse($result, $byId, $child);
            }
        }
    }

    recurse($result, $byId, $arr);    
    return $result;
}

$result = json_encode(convert($legs), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $result;
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/920037). It produces this output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Wendy-Lynn Barr",
        "title": 11312,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Pauline Blake",
                "title": 11303
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Ed Kilgour",
        "title": 5064,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Craig Corbitt",
                "title": 11302,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Kristi  Iles",
                        "title": 5175,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Joshua  Iles",
                                "title": 6013
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Chris Chowning",
                        "title": 6308,
                        "children": [
                                // ...etc
```

The key here is not only recursion, but also referencing a record by its ID (title). This referencing can be done with the `&` symbol, both in function parameters and in assignments.

Comment: foreach($child_3 as $element_2 => $child_4){
$result = json_encode($this->array_filter_recursive($legs), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  give error :- Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: That is not what I meant: you should not iterate over `$child_3`, which might be null. Don't use the nested `foreach` you have. Instead have just one (!) line to define the result, which I presented at the end of my answer.

Comment: i want this result : [ { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager'},]      instead: [{ "0": { "title": "11302", "name": "Craig Corbitt", "referral_id": "5064" }]

Comment: This happens when there is a gap somewhere in your array keys and they do not go nicely from 0 to *n* without interruption. Check your data. Here is an example where it works: [eval.in](https://eval.in/919638)

Comment: I added a solution in my answer for your follow-up question, although you should really treat such questions as new questions. But OK, here it is.

Comment: thank you very much trincot, but i m still unable to get exact formate for Org Chart :   
      {'name': 'Lao Lao', 'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [{ 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
      'children': [{ 'name': 'Li Xin', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
      'children': [{' ': '', '' : ' '}]]},};

Comment: Org Chart? What is that? 'Lao Lao' appears nowhere in your question, nor in the data you provided there. I have no idea what you are referring to or asking.

Comment: An organization chart or "org chart," as it's more commonly known, is a diagram that displays a reporting or relationship hierarchy     https://www.smartdraw.com/organizational-chart/

Comment: Lao Lao is only example

Comment: Can you please provide in your question the desired output for the input you provided (or at least part of it)? But make sure it is based on the same data, so I can understand what gets converted to what.

Comment: "children":[{ "name": "Wendy-Lynn Barr", "title": "11312",
                 "children": [{ "name": "Pauline Blake", "title": "11303",
     "children":[{"name":"Pauline Blake","title":"11312",}]
     }]},{"title": "5064", "name": "Ed Kilgour", "referral_id": "5063",
     'children': [{ 'name': 'Glen Starr', 'title': '6239' },{ 'name': 'Allen Taylor','title': '5155' },{ 'name': 'Roger  Grosser', 'title': '5078' },{ 'name': 'Rodney  Licari', 'title': '5310' },{ 'name': 'Craig Corbitt', 'title':'11302'},{ 'name': 'James Yates', 'title': '5097' },] },{},{},{}
 ]};     this is my desired output

Comment: So the referral_id is a relationship to a parent? You did not mention this in the question... You really need to be more specific.

Comment: OK, after waiting for a while to see you add it to your question I now did it for you.  See updated answer.